# Differential Structure of Two Dimensional Manifold

Tags: soft-question, differential-topology

I am a beginner in Differential Topology, and have learnt that

> **Theorem** One dimensional differential manifold without boundary is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb S$.

- So I am curious about the classification of two dimensional differential manifold. Is it same as the topological situation?
- In even dimension, we can consider the complex situation. That is to say, how do we classify the compact Riemann surface?

Any help in thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in the theorem, you have to assume that manifolds are connected.

Next, it is a theorem (Rado and Caratheodory, I think), that every topological surface has a smooth structure and that two surfaces are homeomorphic if and only if they are diffeomorphic.

See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96670/classification-of-surfaces-and-the-top-diff-and-pl-categories-for-manifolds) for more references than you probably wanted.

As for Riemann surfaces: if you want to classify them up to biholomorphic maps, then things become complicated. Restrict to genus $g\ge 2$ compact surfaces. Then the space of complex structures is a complex manifold of dimension $3g-3$, called the moduli space. For $g=1$, the moduli space is 1-dimensional, while for the sphere (genus zero), the complex structure is unique.

Comment: If the surface is compact manifold with boundary, is "every topological surface has a smooth structure and that two surfaces are homeomorphic if and only if they are diffeomorphic" still true? Thanks!

Comment: @SmartYao: Yes. You do not even need compactness.

Comment: Thanks! It seems pretty different from 1-dimensional case: the noncompact $\mathbb{R}^1$ under standard topology admits many differential structures.

Comment: @SmartYao: The uniqueness is understood "up to a diffeomorphism." Then every topological manifold of  dimension at most 3 admits a unique differentiable structure. What you mean is "unequal maximal smooth atlases," which is totally different.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for pointing out my mistake!